# Can't get all of the data I want out of a join

Tags: hive, hql

I have a hive table that has some http sessions that I need to analyze. One column has a http session ID that is consistent throughout the entire session.

I'm trying find all rows that are part of sessions where one of a certain set of actions was performed AND the session ended in a timeout.

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;

SELECT * FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT id, x_date, y
FROM log
WHERE ((to_date(x_date)) >= (date_sub(current_date, 1)))
AND y like '%timeout%') u

JOIN

(SELECT id, x_date, y, z, q, a 
FROM log
WHERE ((to_date(x_date)) >= (date_sub(current_date, 1)))
AND z in ('1', '2', '3', '4')) o

ON u.id = o.id
ORDER BY u.id, o.x_date;
```

What I'm trying to find is all rows where

```
id = 123 and y like '%timeout%' 
AND (id = 123 and z in('1','2','3','4')
```

What I am currently getting is something like

```
if  (id = 123 and y like %timeout%)
select * where (id = 123 and z in ('1','2','3','4'))
```

The expected output should be much larger than the actual output, as I should get many lines that only has ID = 123.

The problem is I need this for all IDs that meet both criteria, so I have to actually find all of the IDs first :)

I hope this makes sense, I feel like I may have worded the question in a confusing manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it would work in SQL, I'm not super versed in Hive, but it should work based on what I've read.

```
SELECT id, x_date, y, z, q, a
FROM log
WHERE z IN ('1','2','3','4','5') 
      AND id IN (
         SELECT id
         FROM log
         WHERE ((to_date(x_date)) >= (date_sub(current_date, 1)))
               AND y like '%timeout%')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I couldn't get it to work... might end up having to break this up into multiple queries :(